# What is the IUPAC name of this organic compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, alcohols, halides

Variety is the spice of life. I have made an organic compound myself. Can you please tell me the name?
I thought that the correct answer is -
**3,3-dibromo-2,4-dichloro-1,4-difluoro-2,4-diiodo-1-methylbutan-1-ol**, because the haloalkane group is to be given in the alphabetical order and the priority of the alcohol group is higher than the haloalkanes.
Is it correct? What will be the derivation of the name if the alcohol group is replaced with hydrogen?
[image: Formula:C5H4OBr2C12F212]

Comment: Find the longest chain, principal functional group gets lowest number.

Comment: You are nearly right, as it is : 4,4-dibromo-3,5-dichloro-2,5-difluoro-3.5-diiodo-pentan-2-ol

Comment: and for the change alcohol -> haloalkane, it suffices to change the suffix ol to donkey because there is no particular suffix for them

Comment: user213305, you've enlightened me.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments; especially since all three answers were not correct (however, @Maurice was very close, just a wrong hyphen).

Answer (score 1):

As of Loong's suggestion, I'd put the answer removing it from comment section: The name should be 4,4-dibromo-3,5-dichloro-2,5-difluoro-3,5-diiodo-pentan-2-ol as Maurice pointed out. However, keep in mind that there are 3 chiral centers within the molecule. But, the indicated name is okay since stereochemistry of the molecule is not shown.

If $\ce{OH}$ group is replaced by $\ce{H}$ atom, the name of new compound is 2,2-dibromo-1,3-dichloro-1,4-difluoro-1,3-diiodopentane. Again, there are still 3 chiral centers within the molecule.